# Spring application low performance when filtering data

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

- I have created Spring application in app engine B2, I can see in logs
  that application takes 1s to complete data filtering(after wakening
  application up). When in my local machine it takes 10ms. Data size is
  really small and logic is not so complex, just begining of the
  project.

So my questions is it possible that my app engine instance are lacking of some resources or smth? Maybe I am lacking of some configuration or JAVA OPTIONS, because now I use default. Maybe someone has faced similar permormance issues.

Update. Again I have tried to use B1 B2 B4 instances. Same results. Feels like the applications has really small amount of resources.

Problem solved, when I created Compute Engine VM. In virtual machine I have running docker image with the same application. And now it works fine. Responses are great.

I would love to use App Engine, but still cannot figure out what causes this. I use all default settings of app.yaml from google tutorials with no additional options.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the steps or documentation consulted for deploying your App Engine application? Perhaps the was a dependency missed when setting up your environment. Also, can you provide more details as to how your data is being handled or processed in your application? Are there any other operations executed aside from the filtering?

Comment: How to set up : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime
I have updated my question with more details and updates on my work.

Comment: Did you look at the logs? Do you see strange entry or unexpected entry?

Comment: Yes logs does not show that instance is lacking of resources. Nothing related with that

Answer (score 1):

Slowness may come because of less number of CPU or less memory. You can try below app.yaml.
You can place it in src\main\appengine folder. To run it, you can use
mvn clean package appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.projectId=**projectIdName**

```
runtime: java
env: flex
# Application Resources
resources:
  cpu: 4
  memory_gb: 16
  disk_size_gb: 200
# Automatic Scaling
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
  cool_down_period_sec: 120
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
```

Comment: Yes I think the same, that CPU tweaks on filter operation and App Engine, standart enviroment cannot deal with it some how. I will try to use flex again with these options.